# Terminate infinite IO loop in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

In order to facilitate reading a user-specified file while handling bad input, I've written this function:

```
readGetFile :: IO FilePath -> IO String
readGetFile getName =
    catch (getName >>= readFile) (\e->do
        let err = show (e :: IOException)
        printf "Couldn't open file %v. Please enter a valid filename.\n" err
        readGetFile getName >>= return)
```

*This question is not about this function, and it is just used to illustrate a point.*

If I call this function from GHCi, and eventually enter a good filename, it works as expected. However, if I try to terminate it early by hitting <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd></kbd>, strange things happen.

```
*Input> readGetFile getLine
{BadFile.jpeg
}Couldn't open file BadFile.jpeg: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory). Please enter a valid filename.
{^C}Couldn't open file <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file. Please enter a valid filename.
{^C}CouInterrupted.
ldn't p*Input> e file <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file. Please enter a valid filename.
{^C}Couldn't open file <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file. Please enter a valid filename.

*Input> {
}Couldn't open file : openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory). Please enter a valid filename.
```

Note that text in `{}` is entered by me (and I did not type `{}`). `{^C}` is me just hitting <kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd></kbd>.

Obviously, the recursion is continuing to run and read from stdin, even as GHCi tries to resume running.

**How can I terminate this loop from within GHCi?**

*Note: I have done `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`. This question is not about the implementation of `readGetFile` and an answer **must** answer the bolded question above. An answer **may** provide a better way of implementing `readGetFile` in addition if the answer provides reasoning for why it is nicer in respect to keyboard interrupts while still achieving the desired goal.*

This apparently only occurs on Windows. I am on Windows running a default installation of Haskell Platform Core.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is [a known issue in GHCi](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13359).

> Thanks for the report, this seems to be an issue with the mingw-w64
>   runtime. I haven't narrowed it down yet, but essentially something
>   seems to be eating the events and it never reaches ghci.
>
> `CtrlHandler` is never called.
>
> The following example shows the issue. It works when compiled using
>   the Microsoft compiler but doesn't with mingw-w64's GHC.
>
> ```
> #include <windows.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) {   switch( fdwCtrlType )   {
>     // Handle the CTRL-C signal.
>     case CTRL_C_EVENT:
>       printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
>       Beep( 750, 300 );
>       return( TRUE );
>
>     // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit.
>     case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
>       Beep( 600, 200 );
>       printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
>       return( TRUE );
>
>     // Pass other signals to the next handler.
>     case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
>       Beep( 900, 200 );
>       printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
>       return FALSE;
>
>     case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
>       Beep( 1000, 200 );
>       printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
>       return FALSE;
>
>     case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
>       Beep( 750, 500 );
>       printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
>       return FALSE;
>
>     default:
>       return FALSE;   } }
>
> int main( void ) {   if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) )   {
>     printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" );
>     printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" );
>     printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" );
>     printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" );
>
>     while( 1 ){ }   }   else   {
>     printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
>     return 1;   } return 0; }
> ```
>
> This also doesn't work in an msys2 console, even though it appears to.
>   In the case of msys2 bash is disabling `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` so that
>   `CTRL+C` is not processed by the system and is reported as a input
>   stream. Bash is then just terminating the process by force.
>
> In the case of GHCi, something does clearly happen with the runtime
>   since it suddenly starts allocating a large amount of memory and
>   enters some kind of deadlock. So there are two separate issues here.

(Note: I did not create this issue. It appears to have been first reported 2017-03-01. The issue is currently labeled as not an x86 issue but as effecting unknown/multiple architectures.)